# how to hide and play audio tag on a button click

Tags: javascript, jquery, audio

I need to hide an audio tag and play it by clicking on a button.
I treid - `$('#audio').play();` and `$('#audio').triger('play');` - without result.

In the snippet below there is no source file, but it exists in reality. It plays normaly by clicking on play `controls` button.

```js
$('button').on('click', function(){
    $('#audio').play();
    //$('#audio').triger('play'); - also tried
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<audio controls id='audio'><source src="audio/clock.mp3" type="audio/mpeg"></audio>

<button>PLAY</button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As `$('#audio')` is a jquery object `.play()` won't work because it is not a function related to jquery. Use `$('#audio').get(0).play()` to play the file using jquery

```js
$('button').on('click', function(){
    $('#audio').get(0).play();
    
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<audio  id='audio'><source src="audio/clock.mp3" type="audio/mpeg"></audio>

<button>PLAY</button>
```

Or do it using JavaScript

```js
$('button').on('click', function(){
    document.getElementById('audio').play();
    
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<audio  id='audio'><source src="audio/clock.mp3" type="audio/mpeg"></audio>

<button>PLAY</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
document.getElementById("audio").play();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<audio controls id='audio' style='display:none'><source src="audio/clock.mp3" type="audio/mpeg"></audio>

$("button").on('click', function(){
document.getElementById("audio").play();

});
```

you can try this.. i added style part to audio tag

Answer (score 1):

What I understand is that you want to hide/play the audio when you click on the button then show/stop it back when click again.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    // Play flag
    var isPlaying = false;
    var audio = $('#audio')[0];
    var playBtn = $('#playBtn');

    // On click event
    playBtn.click(function() {
      if (!isPlaying) {
          playAudio();
      } else {
          stopAudio();
      }
    });

    function playAudio() {
      // set the flag to true
      isPlaying = true;
      // Play your audio
      audio.play();
      // Hide it
      $(audio).attr('hidden', 'hidden');
      // Change the button text to STOP
      playBtn.text('STOP');
    }

    function stopAudio() {
      // Set flag to false
      isPlaying = false;
      // Pause your audio
      audio.pause();
      // uncomment this if you want to reset the audio
      // audio.currentTime = 0;

      // Show it again
      $(audio).removeAttr('hidden');
      // Change the text back to play
      playBtn.text('PLAY');
    }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<audio controls id="audio" src="audio/clock.mp3"></audio>
<button id="playBtn">PLAY</button>
```

---

If you just want to play and hide it, try this:

```js
var audio = $('#audio')[0];
var playBtn = $('#playBtn');

// On click event
playBtn.click(function() {
    // Play your audio
    audio.play(); 
    // Hide it
    $(audio).attr( 'hidden', 'hidden' );
    // Remove this if you don't want to change the button text
    playBtn.text('PLAYING');
});
```